# Jenkins - failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (but if I click on "compile" in IntelliJ it works)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea, maven-compiler-plugin

I have an automation project on IntelliJ that I connected to a maven project in Jenkins.
When I click on "Build Now" it always failed.

This is the error I got:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8uIZ.png)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project automation-framework: Error while storing the mojo status: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]

The goals on the project configurations are: clean compile.
clean - working.
compile - failing.

If I click on this commands in the project on IntelliJ - it working completly fine.

The java version is 17, both in IntelliJ and Jenkins.
This is how my pom.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation-framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried to change java version to 11.0.2 but it also not working.

Comment: What's the part that mentions `maven-compiler-plugin`? How is IntelliJ connected to Jenkins? Is that one line the entire error message?

Comment: First if you like to build with JDK17 (source/target) you should use JDK17+ furthermore better would be to use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` instead. Also check your build first on plain command outside of any IDE and posting the full pom file here could help otherwise it's impossible even guess what's wrong..

Comment: That doesn't actually tell me anything. Simple question: which versions of Maven are installed locally and on Jenkins, and which one is available to the Jenkins job?

Comment: @nitind
The maven project in Jenkins is connected to IntelliJ through the pom.xml file (in the automation project)
The configuration in the maven project has a field "Build" with the location of the pom file.

Comment: @nitind locally, the Maven version is 3.9.3
in Jenkins - the version of the Maven Integration plugin is 3.23